# How to bind descriptors dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, reduction, python-descriptors

In `ManagmentSystem` I have a basic descriptor setup, binding attributes by name to the `Employee` descriptor class in a loop.

I want to do this dynamically, passing values to `init` to bind them to descriptors then assigning them values.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def get_employee_data():
    return {
        'bob': {
            'id': '12039123',
            'age': 90,
            'occupation': 'manager'
        },
        'john': {
            'id': '43434433',
            'age': 66,
            'occupation': 'janitor'
        },
        'hannah': {
            'id': '48484839',
            'age': 1,
            'occupation': 'professional hamster'
        },
    }


class EmployeeDetail:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objType=None):
        logging.info(
            f'Accessing {self.public_name}')
        #return 'read attribute from data sheet'

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        logging.info(
            f'Accessing {self.public_name}')
        # overwrite attribute to data sheet
        logging.info(
            f'Setting: {value}')

class Employee:

    # I could bind descriptors here to 'EmployeeDetail' but then I can't pass attribute names from 'ManagmentSystem'

    def __init__(self, details):
        for key, value in details.items():
            # I want each 'key' name to be bound to the descriptor
            setattr(self, key, value) # ...then assign the 'value' to the 'key' name

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objType=None):
        logging.info(f'Accessing employee: {self.public_name}')
        return self

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if hasattr(obj, self.private_name):
            logging.info(
                f'Accessing employee: {self.public_name}\nSetting: {value}')
        else:
            logging.info(
                f'Adding employee and setting: {self.public_name}')
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)


class ManagementSystem:

    # class attribute declaration (descriptor pointing)
    for employee in get_employee_data():
        locals()[employee] = Employee(get_employee_data()[employee])

    # attribute assignment on object instantiation
    def __init__(self):
      for employee in get_employee_data():
        #can I bind descriptors here instead of in the class?
        setattr(self, employee, employee)


ms = ManagementSystem()
```

Here is an example of how this could look/be used:

```
>>> ms.hannah
Accessing employee: hannah
<__main__.Employee object at 0x00000230AF4185E0>

>>> ms.hannah.id
Accessing employee: hannah
Accessing id:
'48484839'

>>> ms.hannah.id = 84762
Accessing employee: hannah
Accessing: id
Setting: 84762
```

Is this possible dynamically? Or will have have to hard code my expected attribute names to descriptors in the class as usual?

Thank you as always :)

Comment: Using `vars` and `setattr` is confusing -- why not just use dicts so you don't have any code duplication at all?

Comment: I'm quite new to python in general, thank you I'll look into how I should implement in this way.

Comment: @Samwise I've been trying to implement a solution using dicts but I cannot seem to get it working, I've been attempting to access the class dict and update it within the __init__ (the same given by locals() in the class declaration) so that my attributes point to the descriptor before being assigned values.

Comment: I'd submit an answer with a code example but honestly I'm having a hard time figuring out what this code is supposed to be *doing*.  Why do you want to set all of these fields as class variables *and* instance variables?  How are `Employee` and `ManagementSystem` intended to be used?

Comment: @Samwise I've updated my question's code with an example of use and hopefully this better reflects my intentions.

It's best described that I'm trying to dynamically bind attributes to a descriptor within the `init`. This is so that `ManagmentSystem` utilize `Employee` attributes as decriptors, and down the line I can pass values into `Employee` so I can generate its own descriptors `EmployeeDetail`.

In the future - Through `ManagementSystem` I will be able to do specific operations on an `Employee` object, while corresponding `EmployeeDetail` objects read and write to a data sheet